# How to set gravity position to bottom right of parent?

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I am adding button in FrameLayout at run time, that I want to set at bottom|right of parent.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lp.gravity = **Gravity.RIGHT**; 
        mSelf.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

How can I do it, any suggestion?

Comment: use a RelativeLayout to achieve this..

Comment: what is the parent layout of the framelayout you are adding?

Comment: FrameLayout is the parent layout in which I am adding ImageButton...any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Add a relative layout inside of your framelayout and add components in that relativelayout 
**EDIT with sample**

```
FrameLayout fr = ..... // get your layout here.
RelativeLayout mRel =  new RelativeLayout(your_activity_context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = mRel.getLayoutParams();
Button mBtn = new Button(this); // Component you want to add at BOTTOM RIGHT
mParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM | RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
mBtn.setLayoutParams(mParams);
mRel.add(mBtn);
fr.add(mRel);
```

Note :- There will be some minor change in the code if you add this code in your activity. because I wrote this here only. Not tested. But this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It may help you.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout);
mVideo = new VideoView(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); // or wrap_content
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
relativeLayout.addView(mVideo , layoutParams);
```

Comment: dear, in my case parent view is FrameLayout, I already have some other component child in that. So is it possible to perform same direct between Parent(FramLayout) and Child(ImageButton).